# Change text on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I want to change a text of selected input to `ccc`. I tried using `.hover`, but nothing happened.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".xxx").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next().html("bbb");
        $(this).parents(".checkbox").toggleClass("selected");
      } else {
        $(this).next().html("aaa");
        $(this).parents(".checkbox").toggleClass("selected");
      } 
    });
  });
  $(".checkbox.selected").each(function() {
    $(this)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      $(this).find("p").html("ccc");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      $(this).find("p").html("bbb");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.checkbox.selected:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="xxx" type="checkbox"/>                     
    <p>aaa</p>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="xxx" type="checkbox"/>                     
    <p>aaa</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns an empty jQuery collection, because no check boxes have the `selected` class when it runs:

```
$(".checkbox.selected")
```

Instead, you could use a **[delegated](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)** event handler like this:

```
$(document)
  .on('mouseover', '.checkbox.selected', function() {
    $(this).find("p").html("ccc");
  })
  .on('mouseout', '.checkbox.selected', function() {
    $(this).find("p").html("bbb");
  });
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".xxx").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next().html("bbb");
        $(this).parents(".checkbox").toggleClass("selected");
      } else {
        $(this).next().html("aaa");
        $(this).parents(".checkbox").toggleClass("selected");
      } 
    });
  });
  
  $(document)
    .on('mouseover', '.checkbox.selected', function() {
      $(this).find("p").html("ccc");
    })
    .on('mouseout', '.checkbox.selected', function() {
      $(this).find("p").html("bbb");
    });
});
```

```css
.checkbox.selected:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="xxx" type="checkbox"/>                     
    <p>aaa</p>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input class="xxx" type="checkbox"/>                     
    <p>aaa</p>
  </label>
</div>
```